# In Fireworks how to make a pictogram icon with partially overlapping stroke/outline

Tags: icon, adobe-fireworks

In Adobe Fireworks CS5 how to make a pictogram style icon like this one:

[image]

Or more precisely, **how to get the overlapping stroke/outline of the star atop the bottle without using a stroke filter?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following solution:

When already having the bottle path,

1. Create a star with the auto shape star tool and place it on a layer above the bottle path.
2. Duplicate the star (CTRL + Shift + D) to a layer above the bottle path
3. Select the duplicated star and press CTRL + T or just Q to enable resizing
4. While holding down Alt + Shift, drag one of the corner handles of the duplicated star to make it bigger
5. On the duplicated star grab the yellow handle to control Roundness 1 to make the tips a little "softer"
6. Select the bottle path and the duplicated star. From the Path panel > Combine Paths > Punch Paths
7. Apply the inner shadow with the filters as needed.

An illustration of the result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

without a stroke? dupe the star, scale it by some amount, place behind star, but in front of bottle, merge if needed for mask etc.

You basically work in black only, then you create an inner shadow for the drop shadow effect.

See http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Fireworks/10.0_Using/WS4c25cfbb1410b0021e63e3d1152b00d08d-7ffa.html but replace the @ symbol in your mind with any black shape

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. In my solution I have duplicated and scaled the star as you said.

Answer (score 0):

Add an `Inner Shadow` (Drop Shadow works, too) filter with an opacity of 100, blur of 0 (or 1), and a distance of 1. Use whatever angle you think feels right (usually in increments of 90 degrees works). Make sure to choose a color that contrasts, too.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but that was not really what I was after. Perhaps I should have phrased the question differently. I know how to apply an inner shadow. It was more the "cutting into" the bottle shape with the star outline I was looking for.